# DeprecationWarning in Gensim `most_similar`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

While implementating Word2Vec in Python 3.7, I am facing an unexpected scenario related to depreciation. My question is what exactly is the depreciation warning with respect to 'most_similar' in word2vec gensim python?

Currently, I am getting the following issue.

**DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `most_similar` (Method will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.wv.most_similar() instead).
model.most_similar('hamlet')
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `int` to `np.signedinteger` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.int32 == np.dtype(int).type`.
if np.issubdtype(vec.dtype, np.int):**

Please help to curb this issue? Any help is appreciated.

The code what, I have tried is as follows.

```
import re
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

sentences = list(gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-hamlet.txt'))   
print('Type of corpus: ', type(sentences))
print('Length of corpus: ', len(sentences))

for i in range(len(sentences)):
    sentences[i] = [word.lower() for word in sentences[i] if re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+', word)]
print(sentences[0])    # title, author, and year
print(sentences[1])
print(sentences[10])
model = Word2Vec(sentences=sentences, size = 100, sg = 1, window = 3, min_count = 1, iter = 10, workers = 4)
model.init_sims(replace = True)
model.save('word2vec_model')
model = Word2Vec.load('word2vec_model')
model.most_similar('hamlet')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a warning  which that it's about to become obsolete and non-functional.

> Usually things are deprecated for a few versions giving anyone using them enough time to move to the new method before they are removed.

They've moved `most_similar` to [`wv`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/deprecated/word2vec.html)

So `most_simliar()` should look something like:

```
model.wv.most_similar('hamlet')
```

[src ref](http://pydoc.net/gensim/3.2.0/gensim.models.word2vec/)

Hope this helps

Edit : using `wv.most_similar()`

```
import re
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

sentences = list(gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-hamlet.txt'))   
print('Type of corpus: ', type(sentences))
print('Length of corpus: ', len(sentences))

for i in range(len(sentences)):
    sentences[i] = [word.lower() for word in sentences[i] if re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+', word)]
print(sentences[0])    # title, author, and year
print(sentences[1])
print(sentences[10])
model = Word2Vec(sentences=sentences, size = 100, sg = 1, window = 3, min_count = 1, iter = 10, workers = 4)
model.init_sims(replace = True)
model.save('word2vec_model')
model = Word2Vec.load('word2vec_model')
similarities = model.wv.most_similar('hamlet')
for word , score in similarities:
    print(word , score)
```

Comment: Thanks Madhan. I have tried this model.wv.most_similar('hamlet'). But, it displays the following error, "utureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `int` to `np.signedinteger` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.int32 == np.dtype(int).type`.
  if np.issubdtype(vec.dtype, np.int):"

Comment: Yeah. it's coming from `numpy` a  dependency used by gensim. Genism are fixing it in newer version ref : https://github.com/brian-team/brian2/issues/918 . Mean while you can try by downgrading numpy to 1.13 : 
[ref]( https://github.com/brian-team/brian2/issues/918#issuecomment-364865331)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Its mean a lot. How to downgrade the numpy to 1.13?

Comment: No worries :) `pip uninstall numpy`. and then `pip install numpy==1.13`

Comment: pip3 right? This is because I am using 3.7 version python.

Comment: Yep sir. `pip3` it is

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot. The error is resolved but `model.wv.most_similar()` is not working and not displaying the similarity score.

Comment: @MishraSiba Are you iterating it properly ? Because I got list of (word, similarity). `[('ophelia', 0.9984570741653442), ('oh', 0.9984418749809265), ('horatio', 0.998319149017334), ('deere', 0.9981393218040466), ('laertes', 0.997983992099762), ('noble', 0.9978675842285156), ('deare', 0.997803270816803), ('sweet', 0.9978032112121582), ('ghost', 0.9977996945381165), ('ho', 0.9977580308914185)]`

Comment: What do you mean by proper iteration? The parameters used in the model is shown above code snippet. Please help, if i am using some weird parameter.

Comment: @MishraSiba I've edited the code . Can you check this please ?

Comment: @MishraSiba No worries. Glad I could be of any help :)

Answer (score 3):

A deprecation warning is a warning to indicate the use of things that may or may not exist in future versions of Python, often replaced by other things. (tells what they are)

It appears that the errors originate inside of Word2Vec, and not your code. Removing these errors would entail going into that library and changing its code.

Try doing what it tells you to do.

Change your `model.most_similar('hamlet')` to `model.wv.most_similar('hamlet')`

I am unfamiliar with this package, so adjust to how it would work for your use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How to do that?

Comment: I edited it. I copypasted wrong. It SHOULD work as `model.wv.most_similar('hamlet')`

Comment: Now, it throws the following error, "utureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `int` to `np.signedinteger` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.int32 == np.dtype(int).type`.
  if np.issubdtype(vec.dtype, np.int):"

Comment: According to this signature, it doesn't look like you can simply pass it `'hamlet'`

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.most_similar

Try passing, `positive='hamlet'`

Answer (score 0):

So, Gensim here is telling you that eventually you will not be able to use the `most_similar` method directly on the Word2Vec model. Instead, you will need to call it on the `model.wv` object, which are the keyed vectors that are stored when you train a model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, I too tried the model.wv.most_similar but it displays me the following message, "Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `int` to `np.signedinteger` is deprecated".

Comment: This sounds like a warning from `numpy` or some other dependency used by `Gensim`. They would need to change that.

Comment: Shall I upgrade numpy?

Comment: No, because it is code within `Gensim` or some dependcy that is using that deprecated conversion method.

Answer (score 0):

After the update to 4.0.0 version, the function model.most_similar() will be removed. So what you can do is to modify the function to model.wv.most_similar(). The same goes for the function model.similarity(). You have to change it to model.wv.similarity().